# How to use filter method instead of for in loop? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to assign the `BookingFeedback` property of each element of `bookings` array to `arrayOfFeedBackValues`. Is there a shorter version than for in loop?

```
     //long version
  let bookings = [FireBaseData]()
  var arrayOfFeedBackValues = [Double]()
       for item in bookings{
          if item.BookingFeedback != nil {
            arrayOfFeedBackValues.append(Double(item.BookingFeedback)!)
           }
       }

//attempted short version. How can I make the returned value be of type Double?
  var arrayOfFeedBackValues = bookings.filter {$0.BookingFeedback != nil}
```

Comment: use flatMap maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map`

```
arrayOfFeedBackValuesa.append(contentsOf: 
                               bookings.filter {$0.BookingFeedback != nil}
                                       .map { Double($0.BookingFeedback)! })
```

Comment: That's nice. I will accept the answer once I am allowed to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this i think

```
var arrayOfFeedBackValues: [Double] = bookings.flatMap { $0.BookingFeedback == nil ? nil : Double($0.BookingFeedback!) }
```